# Python -- How to make an event loop in the console

Tags: python, events, python-2.7, event-loop, keyboardinterrupt

Using Python 2.7, how would I make an event loop that I can run my program inside? My idea is that the script will run, and the event loop will detect the press of a certain key (<kbd>q</kbd> in this case), that will do the same thing as `Keyboard Interupt`, just slightly prettier.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064373/basic-event-loop-in-python), but wasn't sure how to apply it.

Also, like the OP of the linked question, I'd like to do this without any external modules/packages (if possible).

I can post my program code if you need it, but I don't think it's relevant in this case.

Comment: See this answer for an example using the curses library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718561/python-3-how-to-input-data-without-pressing-return-in-osx

Comment: @bwbrowning Thanks but I'm on Windows (for this script) and don't have curses...